python recursion error, calling classmethod of derived class in __new__ method
I have the following piece of code - simplified version of what I want to do.
But it gives me a recursion error.
class File:
    def __new__(cls, filename):
        extension = filename.split(".")[-1].lower()

        if extension == "csv":
            cls = CSVFile
        elif extension == "json":
            cls = JSONFile
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Unsupported file extension: {extension}")

        # instance = super().__new__(cls)  # this works
        instance = cls.create_instance(filename)
        return instance

class CSVFile(File):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename

    @classmethod
    def create_instance(cls, filename):
        print("CSVFile, create_instance")
        return cls(filename)

class JSONFile(File):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename

    @classmethod
    def create_instance(cls, filename):
        print("JSONFile, create_instance")
        return cls(filename)

# Example usage
file_instance = File("data.csv")
print(f"File instance: {file_instance.filename}")

Do you have idea how to make it work?

I'm not sure what your later goal is, but why not something like this?
from pathlib import Path

class File:
    def __init__(self, filename: Path):
        self.filename = filename.name

    def parse(self) -> Any:
        raise NotImplementedError()
    
class CSVFile(File):
    pass

class JSONFile(File):
    pass

def get_file(filename: Path) -> File:
    """Get a file by its name."""
    match filename.suffix:
        case ".csv":
            return CSVFile(filename)
        case ".json":
            return JSONFile(filename)
        case _:
            raise ValueError(f"Unsupported file type: {filename.suffix}")


Hi! Thanks! The solution like you proposed works, also the one with e.g. staticmethod on File class. I have learn recently, that the recommended way with factory method is to define it in new so I wanted to try this approach in my code.

__new__ indirectly invokes itself when subclass create_method methods call cls.
If you want a factory method, define a distinct one instead of trying to hijack __new__ for the purpose.
File("data.cvs" invokes File.__new__(File, "data.csv") which invokes CSVFile.create_method("data.csv") which invokes CSVFile("data.csv") which calls CSVFile.__new__(CSVFile, "data.csv") which, because CSVFile.__new__ isn't defined, calls File.__new__(CSVFile, "data.csv")... which invokes CSVFile.create_method("data.csv") which ...

Ok, thanks. I actually learnt recently that the new method is the right place for factory that's why, I tried to make it work with new.
Is there any way to avoid this recursion?
In the above code, when I call: instance = super().new(cls) instead, there is no recursion.

super().__new__ resolves to object.__new__ in this case, which actually creates the new instance of class cls, according to the argument it receives. No recursion, because you bypass the call to a subclass's method.(__new__ is not actually a class method: it's specially cased as a static method.)

__new__'s job is to create a new instance, not to decide which class to instantiate.
